# Renaming messages but it shows "Operation not permitted" on linux system

Tags: linux, message

I'm using Centos 8.0 and my kernel version:
4.18.0-147.5.1.x86_64

**Backgroud**:
The messages on my host not rotated for a long time,and when I use "logrotate -v -f" to force rotating messages, it shows "rename messages: Operation not permitted".So I try renaming the messages immediately.

```
-rw-------    1 root    15464299992 Jul 15 10:12 messages
-rw-------    1 root       11644353 Sep  7  2020 messages-20200907.gz
-rw-------    1 root        8834073 Sep 13  2020 messages-20200913.gz
```

```
renaming /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20210715
error: failed to rename /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20210715: Operation not permitted
```

Here is my operation and the terminal's output:

```
[root@node-5 log]# mv messages messages-20210715
mv: cannot move ‘messages’ to ‘messages-20210715’: Operation not permitted
[root@node-5 ~]# whoami
root
```

I login as root,why do I still come across such problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `ls -ald .` show? Who is the owner of the log directory and what are the permissions?  You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

@DavidC.Rankin
Thx for replying.Here is the `ls -ald .` for messages:

```
[root@node-5 log]# ls -ald
drwxr-xr-x. 30 root 8192 Jul 15 11:14 .
```

So I don't think this may be a problem about permissions.
I also used `strace` to follow the syscall:

```
stat("messages2", 0x7fff6c37aae0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("messages", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=15464637645, ...}) = 0
lstat("messages2", 0x7fff6c37a790)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "messages", AT_FDCWD, "messages2", 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Unfortunately,there are too many branches in function `do_renameat2` so I haven't found the exact exit yet.

Comment: Notice the UID `30`. To fix this use `chown root:root .` (or full-path `chown root:root /var/log`) Somehow the owner of the directory was changed to UID `30` which prevented logrotate from running and you from being able to rename. When done run logrotate again and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved:
Show the file attributes with `lsattr`, it seems that messages got an attribute 'a',so it can't be renamed.

```
---------------- ./maillog-20201004
-----a---------- ./messages
```

And with command `chattr -a messages`,messages can be renamed again.